# Algorithm to find smallest number of points to cover area (war game)

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I'm dealing with a war game. I have a list of my bases `B(x,y)` from which I can send attacks on the enemy (they have bases between my own bases). Each base `B` can attack at a range `R` (the same *radius* for all bases). How can I find my bases to be able to attack as many enemy bases as possible, but use a minimum number of my bases?

I've reduced the problem to finding the minimum number of bases (and their coordinates) required to cover the largest area possible. I wonder if there is a better way than looking at all the possible combinations and because the number of bases could reach thousands.

Example: If the attack radius is 10 and I have five bases in a square and its center: `(0,0)`, `(10,0)`, `(10,10)`, `(0,10)`, `(5,5)` then the answer is that only the first four would be needed because all the area covered by the one in the center is already covered by the others.

**Note 1** The solution must be single-threaded.

**Note 2** The solution doesn't have to be perfect if that means a big gain in speed. The number of bases reaches thousands and this needs to use as little time as possible. I would consider running time greater than 100 ms for 10,000 bases in Python on a modern computer unacceptable, so I was thinking maybe I could start by eliminating the obvious, like if there are multiple bases within `R/10` distance of each other, simply eliminate all except for one (whichever).

Comment: "the minimum number of bases required to cover the largest area possible" does not seem to be a well defined objective; as long as there is no overlap, you achieve the minimum number of bases for the area they cover, so the answer will be the largest configuration that has no overlap; but I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: "The answer should be the largest configuration that has no overlap". If the surfaces covered by 2 bases overlap only 1% but the rest 99% of each covers a unique area, then I'd very much prefer overlapping. As I mentioned in my second note, maybe eliminating "obvious" overlaps (eg, 90% or more) would severely speed things up.

Comment: I would start with just random placement of your bases, with a measurement of the coverage of enemy bases, and define a stopping criterion (such as that many bases, that percentage of coverage...). You can do blind placement (don't even look where you place them) or use heuristics (if you land close to an existing base, choose to discard one of them...). But it needs to be fast, to allow you try many placements. Then you can think of simulated annealing, i.e. local changes of the configuration on smaller and smaller scale.

Comment: I think we might need more clarification on the optimization objective. In your post you wrote "How can I find my bases to be able to attack as many enemy bases as possible, but use a minimum number of my bases?", I assumed that made "attacking as many enemy bases" your primary and "using a minimum number of your bases" the secondary objective, but from your comment I have the feeling your desired optimal solution is somewhere in between...?

Comment: @jpmath: It's about surface area. The solution should find the minimum number of bases, but since this is a practical problem about a game (not a theoretical problem) the perfect solution doesn't mean finding exactly those bases, but trying to get as close as possible to finding them with reasonable CPU time (reasonable in the context that I have thousands of bases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum the solution depends on your needs. If you need real time answer, maybe a greedy algorithm could provide good solution.
Other solution could be using meta-heuristic with constraint time(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic). I probably would use genetic algorithm to search a solution for this problem under a limited time.

If interested I can provide a toy example of implementation in Python.

EDIT :

When you have to provide solution quickly a greedy algorithm is often better. But in your case I doubt. Particularity of many greedy algorithm is that you need to start from scratch each time you try to compute a new result.

Speaking again of genetic algorithm, you could for example each time you have to take a decision restart the search process from its last result. In fact you could probably let him turning has a subprocess and each 100ms take the better solution computed during the last loop.

If not too greedy in computing resource, this solution would provide better results than greedy one on the long run as the solution will probably need to be adapted to the changes of the situation but many element will stay unchanged. Just be aware that initializing a meta-search with the solution of a greedy algorithm is anyway a good idea!

Comment: Yes, I need to look into metaheuristics. I edited my question to add that the solution doesn't have to be perfect if that means a big gain in speed.

Comment: That's it! I can do a one-time computation and then adjust the results of that one as new information is added. Whenever a base is added or removed, I have to toggle the state (add to response / remove from response) each of the bases it overlaps with and then do the same for those. This will drastically reduce computation time.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, the enemy bases and your bases are given as well as the (constant) attack radius. I.e. if you select one of your bases, you know exactly which of the enemy bases get attacked due to the selection.

The first step would be to eliminate those enemy cities from the problem which can not be attacked by any of your bases. Then, selecting all of your bases guarantees attacking all attackable  enemy bases, so there is solution that attacks as many enemy bases as possible.

Under all those solutions you are looking for the one that uses the minimum number of your bases. This problem is equivalent to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem, which is unfortunately NP-hard. You can apply all known solution methods such as  [Integer Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integer_unknowns) or the already mentioned greedy algorithm / metaheuristics.

If your problem instance is large and runtime is the primary concern, greedy is probably the way to go. For example you could always add that particular base of yours to the selection which adds the highest number of enemy bases that can be attacked which were previously not under attack by your already selected bases.

Comment: Like your greedy algorithm idea ^^